# How to congigure wordpress website with Amazon ELB and cloudfront

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, cpanel, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I have a **Cpanel** server on amazon ec2 with a **wordpress** website with dedicated ip.

> How can I add the wordpress website under a **Amazon ELB**

tried using custom health check with /home/user/public_html/index.php with HTTP:80 and it still shows outofservice

> Also possible to use **cloudfront** for the domain without using Amazon s3.

Comment: Does Wordpress is working fine?

Comment: yes, working fine.

Comment: While adding instance in ELB Classic Load Balancer what error you are getting?